# make this perl script work on window

Tags: regex, perl, batch-file

system("grep \"^2013/$yesterday-\" Log_2013_$yesterday*.txt > Log_2013_$yesterday.txt");

I can't run my perl script that has the code above. It works fine on linux. I think the problem is that perl on window do not have grep command. So Can anyone help me rewrite this so it will work on window.

I was thinking using findstr

Thanks,

Comment: Perl *always* has a `grep` function, Windows does not have a `grep` command.

Comment: I have perl on my window laptop, but it doesnt work. but when I ran the code i a linux machine, it works fine. Do you see the problem?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that Windows *does not* have a `grep` command. You are trying to use a command that doesn't exist. You need to switch to a Windows specific command for it to work.

Comment: Do not have permission to install anything on these laptop.

Comment: So Instead of using system, can I just grep?

Comment: How do i make it work? i have no experience with perl on window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reimplement `grep` in Perl, and then use `system` to call your new `grep` command:

```
# create a new perl script called "grep" in current directory
# put this near the beginning of your script
open GREP, ">grep";
print GREP <<'EOF';
#! perl
$regex = $ARGV[0];
while (<STDIN>) {
    print if $_ =~ $regex;
}
EOF

$yesterday = ...;
system("perl grep \"^2013/$yesterday-\" Log_2013_$yesterday*.txt > Log_2013_$yesterday.txt");

# note that you have to say  system("perl grep ...") now 
# and not just  system('grep ...")
```

Comment: Using fndstr works!!!